# Dokan - Admin commission on shipping depending delivery method

Tags: php, dokan

I am a dokan user, in dokan you can set shipping to vendor or to admin.
Mainly i want to offer the possibility to vendor to choose ( so all shipping cost goes to vendors )

1. Flat rate shipping
2. Collect
3. Free delivery

and i want to add : ( to add it is not a problem )

4. ADMIN delivery service   ---> fees must go to admin and not to vendor.

so any idea how to get Admin delivery service fees in my earning and not to vendors ?

````
                'name'    => 'shipping_fee_recipient',
                'label'   => __( 'Shipping Fee Recipient', 'dokan-lite' ),
                'desc'    => __( 'Who will be receiving the Shipping fees', 'dokan-lite' ),
                'type'    => 'select',
                'options' => array( 'seller' => __( 'Vendor', 'dokan-lite' ), 'admin' => __( 'Admin', 'dokan-lite' ) ),
                'default' => 'seller'
            ),    ```
--> this is the function when i can choose admin or vendor "function file in dokan"
````

Comment: Are you asking that admin will set the shipping not vendors?

Answer (score 1):

If you want that admin will set the shipping not vendors then
You can use this on your child-theme functions.php:

```
remove_filter( 'woocommerce_cart_shipping_packages', 
'dokan_custom_split_shipping_packages' );
remove_filter( 'woocommerce_shipping_package_name', 
'dokan_change_shipping_pack_name');
remove_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_create_order_shipping_item', 
'dokan_add_shipping_pack_meta');`
```